# Assigning a Variable to represent a Block of Code

Tags: python, variables

I'm new to python programming and I have a (maybe) specific question.
I don't know if python lets you do this, but basically i want to assign a variable to represent a whole block of stuff.

for example i have this:

```
item.history[len(item.history)] = {'user': item.user,
                        'email': item.email, 'phone': item.phone,
                        'status': item.status, 'usage': item.usage,
                        'checkouttime': item.checkouttime,
                        'checkintime': item.checkintime,
                        'timeout': item.checkintime - item.checkouttime}
```

this is alot of stuff in one spot, and in my program the same chunk of this code (shown below as ShortHis) is repeated around 15 times, with changes to the history key, and different variables instead of checkintime and checkouttime sometimes, so I figured if i did this:

```
ShortHis = ('user': item.user,
    'email': item.email, 'phone': item.phone,
    'status': item.status, 'usage': item.usage,
    'checkouttime': item.checkouttime,
    'checkintime': item.checkintime,)
```

then this:

```
item.history[len(item.history)] = {ShortHis
                        'timeout': item.checkintime - item.checkouttime}
```

would work and I could save some space, and still be able to edit the key and the checkintime and checkouttime variables, but it does not. 
Why doesn't this work and how can I make something like I'm wanting? (If something like that exists)

I'm sorry if I've left out specific terminology for what these things are called, as I said I'm new to python programming.

**More Clarity:** I want a chunk of stuff, any stuff, regardless of content or length, to be assigned to a variable (or something) that represents that stuff just like it was before, so I can put that variable in the middle of something and it still run as if the original code was there.

Comment: `item.history[len(item.history)]` itself would give you an `IndexError`.   It `item.history` has 10 elements, you are trying to access `item.history[10]`, where the last element is `item.history[9]`.

Comment: I understand that, I will add an edit to better convey what I'm trying to do, if I reinserted this back into my program it would work fine with no IndexError, but as of right now i have this particular block (ShortHis) repeated around 15 times in the program, so I'm trying to make it less bulky by assigning a chunk of it to something.

Comment: it is hard to imagine you actually want to use "item.history[len(item.history)]".  len(item.history) is a count of items(or elements or objects). Are you using the number of items (of a dict) as its record "type"?

Comment: Yep. its weird but it works for what I'm doing.

Comment: You are looking for macro capabilities in Python, which don't exist. In Python it is more common to use functions, so you should restructure your code to use functions.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a good idea to just use a function here

```
def get_short_history(item):
    return {
       'user': item.user,
       'email': item.email,
       'phone': item.phone,
       'status': item.status,
       'usage': item.usage,
       'checkouttime': item.checkouttime,
       'checkintime': item.checkintime
    }
```

you can then reuse this chunk

```
items.history.append(get_short_history(item).update({checkintime: 'overwrite'}))
```

Comment: this almost works, but when i put it in it doesn't understand anything until i add "self." to get_short_history, and even then it cant see item or checkintime

Comment: `self` is only relevant in context of classes, which you don't mention in your example code.

Answer (score 1):

> ... a variable to represent a whole block of stuff.

Then you should be using a [**class**](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html), with optional [**properties**](http://archive.org/details/SeanKellyRecoveryfromAddiction).

```
class Item(object):
  def __init__(self, user, ...):
    self.user = user
     ...

someitem = Item(me, ...)
print someitem.timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "update" method to modify the contents of dictionary. Refer below example:

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2}
dict1.update({'c':3})
```

So create a original dictionary and use modify method to update it instead of storing the values in some temporary variable.

Answer (score 0):

Despite your code in the question works or not, any Python assignment means assigning the reference to the object. This way, **any assigned object is actually shared via one more reference**. In other words, **Python assignment means sharing**.

If the shared chunk is constant, then you can look at it as optimization of the memory space usage. If the shared chunk is not constant, well, then it depends on the original intention.

Any Python variable is a reference to a target object.

Now, if I understand you well, you want to append new record to the history list. The `'timeout'` is special, the `ShortHis` is to be shared. If this is the case, you have to use the new key for the shared chunk (say `'ref'`) and use the `ShortHis` chunk as the value for the key. Something like this:

```
record = { 'timeout': item.checkintime - item.checkouttime,
           'ref': ShortHis }

item.history.append(record)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so perhaps?

```
class Item(object):

    def __init__(self, user='', email='', phone=''):
        self.user = user
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone
        self.time = ''
        self.history = []

    def add_short(self):
        self.time = time.asctime()
        self.history.append( {'user':self.user, 'time': self.time} )

    def add_long(self):
        self.time = time.asctime()
        self.history.append( {'user':self.user, 'email': self.email, 
            'phone': self.phone, 'time': self.time } )
```

Example useage:

```
import time
from pprint import pprint as pp
item = Item('dudely', 'dudely@doright.com', '111-222-3333')
item.add_short()
time.sleep(1)
item.add_short()
time.sleep(1)
item.add_long()
time.sleep(1)
item.add_short()
time.sleep(1)
item.add_long()
pp(item.history)
```

Example output:

```
[{'time': 'Tue Jul 17 04:26:05 2012', 'user': 'dudely'},
 {'time': 'Tue Jul 17 04:26:06 2012', 'user': 'dudely'},
 {'email': 'dudely@doright.com',
  'phone': '111-222-3333',
  'time': 'Tue Jul 17 04:26:07 2012',
  'user': 'dudely'},
 {'time': 'Tue Jul 17 04:26:08 2012', 'user': 'dudely'},
 {'email': 'dudely@doright.com',
  'phone': '111-222-3333',
  'time': 'Tue Jul 17 04:26:09 2012',
  'user': 'dudely'}]
```

Comment: You should not declare class variables